# Python pyttsx is blocking the program in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, text-to-speech

I made a program in Tkinter, where the program have to speak some text after the user has pressed the button. The voice is working, but the problem is that pyttsx is blocking the program during the sound. For example in the program you press the button, then you can hear the voice, and only after that the button animation continues. How can I stop pyttsx from stoping the program? Thanks in advance. Sorry if my English is bad. Here is my exampe code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import pyttsx

def click():
    engine.say('test')
    engine.runAndWait()

engine = pyttsx.init()

window = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(text='here', command=click)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use multi-threading. I suggest looking [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) on how to use the module, but it should allow you to run your pyttsx module without blocking tkinter.